# align 2 table column widths with each other

Tags: html, css

I have 2 tables one on top of the other and I would like to align their column widths exactly with each other, is there a way to do this? Tried fixed table col widths etc no joy

You can see on fiddle the columns are slightly off each other
http://jsfiddle.net/askhe/

HTML

```
<table class="tblresults txtblack">
                            <tr class="tblresultshdr bold">
                                <td class="col1">Company</td>
                                <td>Currency</td>
                                <td>Bid</td>
                                <td>Ask</td>
                                <td>YTD Vol</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col1">ABC</td>
                                <td>GBP</td>
                                <td>94</td>
                                <td>16</td>
                                <td>3,567,900</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col1">DEF</td>
                                <td>GBP</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>46</td>
                                <td>10,000</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col1">GHI</td>
                                <td>GBP</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>46</td>
                                <td>10,000</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col1">JKLM</td>
                                <td>GBP    </td>
                                <td>7</td>
                                <td>46</td>
                                <td>56,000</td>
                            </tr>

</table>
                        <table class="tblresults txtblack margintop10">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5" class="bold" >Investments</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col1">ghjk</td>
                                <td>GBP</td>
                                <td>13</td>
                                <td>6</td>
                                <td>130,000</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col1">asdsa</td>
                                <td>GBP</td>
                                <td>120</td>
                                <td>46</td>
                                <td>16,000</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col1">dfdsfsdf </td>
                                <td>GBP</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>13,000</td>
                            </tr>
                       </table>​
```

CSS

```
table.tblresults {
    width:100%;
    *width:99.5%;
    border: 1px solid #b9b8b8;
    top: 0;
}
table.tblresults tr.tblresultshdr {background: lightgrey;}
table.tblresults tr.tblresultshdr td {padding: 6px;}
table.tblresults td {padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #b9b8b8;}
table.tblresults td.col1 {width: 70%;}
​
```

Comment: Your tables have 100% width so you can use proportional width for columns (or percentage if you prefer). It'll be the same for both columns (until the share they same number of columns).

Comment: Any reason why these two tables can't be combined into one? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/askhe/2/

Comment: The reason i cant combine them is they have data fed from different sources. The above uses dummy data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`table` elements where meant for scientific data, such as probes from experiments, not for actual layout:

> Tables should not be used purely as a means to layout document content as this may present problems when rendering to non-visual media. Additionally, when used with graphics, these tables may force users to scroll horizontally to view a table designed on a system with a larger display. To minimize these problems, authors should use style sheets to control layout rather than tables.

While you're not using them for layout, your problem is actually a rendering/layout issue. The easiest solution to this is to [merge both tables into one (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/askhe/1/).

If you prefer your data to be encapsulated in many little tables instead of one giant table you'll need to specify a width for almost all columns.

Comment: If i don't use tables how should I layout the data, with divs? I thought tables should used for tabular data?!?

Comment: Of course you should use them. Sorry if this wasn't clear. But you're having a rendering issue, you should either pack everything into *one* table, or set a column width for every column. You can also use `<colgroup>`/`<col>` for this instead of CSS.

Comment: Hmm ive tried setting the width for each col which is fine on start but when i shrink the window things start getting a little haywire

Comment: That's why it should be easier to use a single table as suggested by [j08691](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724620/align-2-table-column-widths-with-each-other/11724795#comment15556323_11724620) and [Cypress](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11724875/1139697).

Comment: It would thats how had it setup originally but when looping through data and adding it into a table you cant just switch data source half way through, maybe you can but ill be a bit of work getting it done.

Comment: @Zeta: Like you, I avoid using tables for layouts as much as possible, but, just to play devil's advocate with you, I would tell you that I could easily find a hundred similar articles on `float` because it was designed and meant solely for news article-style text-wrapping around images

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel: Yeah, people are misusing `float` when they need `display:inline-block` or a simple `position:absolute`, they use negative margin because it "just seems right", even if there is a very simple solution. You could fill a book with common CSS mistakes/taboos which are used on a daily basis. But in this case it needs to be a table, I only wanted to point out why they are so tricky sometimes.

Comment: Specifying column widths either with values or percentages both don't produce a correct alignment.

Answer (score 3):

Why not put them in the same table? It seems they are semantically similar.
http://jsfiddle.net/askhe/5/

Answer (score 3):

No need to merge tables, you can use this

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

There is a wonderful article here about it
https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

Comment: i had a similar problem and this was the solution i used

Comment: This does work. But note that you need to have all of these: `width: 100%;` and `table-layout: fixed;` on the table, and each of the first rows of your table need to have a set `width` (percentage is best).

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree that the solution to merge the tables is the best and simplest one in many cases, i came to the need to really have this 2 separate tables with identical columns (to make one table fixed and the 2nd scrollable)

to achieve that, I declared 2 tables with same number of columns, one with width rules (% and px), one without

Then, with Javascript, I applied the width of the ruled table to the free one:

```
document.getElementById("HeaderTable").style.width = document.getElementById("main").clientWidth ;
document.getElementById("tar1").style.width = document.getElementById("org1").clientWidth ;
document.getElementById("tar2").style.width = document.getElementById("org2").clientWidth ;
document.getElementById("tar3").style.width = document.getElementById("org3").clientWidth ;
document.getElementById("tar4").style.width = document.getElementById("org4").clientWidth ;
```

1st line fix the table width, then it's done column by column. Using `.clientWidth` is important, because `.style.width` send a percentage if it's what is applied on the ruled column.

This was almost working, but not quite. Table had a similar layout, but shifted by a few pixels. As I only needed that to be working in IE, I though I could move that with fixed values, to be as close as possible as what I wanted, so I change my code to:

```
document.getElementById("tar1").style.width = document.getElementById("org1").clientWidth - 9;
document.getElementById("tar2").style.width = document.getElementById("org2").clientWidth ;
document.getElementById("tar3").style.width = document.getElementById("org3").clientWidth - 10;
document.getElementById("tar4").style.width = document.getElementById("org4").clientWidth - 10;
```

I guess the values could be different for a different table. But what surprised me, is that it works in every major browser, independently of the zoom level

windows resize breaks the alignement, so you need to bind the function to this event. Also, this solution don't work anymore on extreme size of the table

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rafa28/hoyfhk4r/3/), as some CSS is involved. for the moment it doesn't work on zoom, because my floating header doesn't stick to `right: 0px`, don't know why yet

Answer (score -2):

Well, using this simple HTML snippet you can do it. well in my case i was creating pdf's from HTML, so this solution worked for me. Hope it help some one else.

```
<table border=0>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!--Insert table 1 -->
    </td>
    <td>
      <!--Insert table 2 -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if someone downvotes, at least they should comment why they did it. so, that if I made a mistake I better not make that again.

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't solve the problem. It just puts the two tables next to each other.

Comment: well, i appreciate your response. But, I had clearly mentioned that `i was creating pdf's from HTML`. and which solved my problem.