# align columns of two separate table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two tables and I would like to align the colums of both tables. But I am unable to achieve that.

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <fieldset>
    <table>
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="col-md-3">header1</th>
        <th class="col-md-4">header2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td>azertyuopazertyuiop</td>
        <td>azertyuopazertyuiop</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <table>
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="col-md-3">headerheaderheader1</th>
        <th class="col-md-4">headerheaderheader2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td>azertyuopazertyuio</td>
        <td>azertyuopazertyuio</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </fieldset>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't use a single table in which I put all the data as some suggested. Because I have other html code between both tables, I necessary need two separate tables.

Comment: You want header2 of table1 to align with header2 of table2 even though if table1/table2 have different numbers of headers? I find it strange that you have a table, yet you are using bootstrap to lay it out. Would you be able to post an image or describe your desired result?

Comment: Yes I am using bootstrap

Comment: You can see an answer for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59917823/8285811).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine two tables into one table and rely on html to determine table behavior instead of relying on bootstrap for layout/styling.

```css
#bunch-o-stuff {
  padding: 70px;
}
.th {
  border-top: none !important;
}
.table {
  width: auto !important;
}
.table-borderless > tbody > tr > td,
.table-borderless > tbody > tr > th,
.table-borderless > tfoot > tr > td,
.table-borderless > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-borderless > thead > tr > td,
.table-borderless > thead > tr > th {
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <fieldset>
    <table class="table table-borderless">
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="col-md-3">header1</th>
        <th class="col-md-4">header2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td>azertyuopazertyuiop</td>
        <td>azertyuopazertyuiop</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
  <div id="bunch-o-stuff">
  </div>
  <fieldset>
    <table class="table table-borderless">
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="col-md-3">headerheaderheader1</th>
        <th class="col-md-4">headerheaderheader2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td>azertyuopazertyuio</td>
        <td>azertyuopazertyuio</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </fieldset>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This can be an option, though I haven't tried it to make sure it works. Actually, between the tables I have others html code. For brevity, I did not insert them in my question.

Comment: Ah, I see, good to know. Would you be able to edit your question to include that information?

Comment: I have edited my solution to accommodate your needs, please review, and let me know if that is indeed what you are looking for :) Thank you

Comment: `border: none` is what I was looking for to remove all the style around the rows using bootstrap. For the width, instead of using `auto`, I will specify it to something fitting my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add Bootstrap's `table` class to your tables:

```
<table class="table">
```

**[Bootply example](https://www.bootply.com/x98TwreVqw)**

Comment: This is exactly what I want. But I don't want the line drawn around the header. Second, I don't want the table headers to span on the whole line.

Comment: You can write your own CSS to remove Bootstrap's borders that you don't want. And I don't understand what you mean when you say that you don't want the table headers to span the whole line.

Comment: I mean, I don't want the table rows to occupy the whole line, but only a part of it. Is it more clear?