# Is there a way to align columns in multiple tables in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

See image below:

[image]

Notice how the two tables, separated by dates aren't aligned. (The ZZ column, the XX column, and the third column).

This is because we currently implemented in a way that changes column width according to the text inside. I tried using a fixed width and it did not look good on multiple devices.

Is there a way I can implement this so that

1. The columns are aligned - it would align regardless of the content by either warping or doing something ux-ui/friendly that I'm not aware of
2. It works well on multiple devices.

Comment: Have you taken a look at css grid?

Comment: This is more of a CSS question than it is JS or even ReactJS related. Look in to a CSS Grid platform such as Bootstrap, CSS Grid, Foundation, etc. etc..

Alternatively, you should be able to correct this with simple css.

Comment: You might find some useful hints here => https://hashnode.com/post/really-responsive-tables-using-css3-flexbox-cijzbxd8n00pwvm53sl4l42cx

Comment: It's currently using bootstrap  .table-responsive. Should I flexbox or use CSS grid. (or both?)

Comment: You can see an answer for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59917823/8285811).

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of bootstraps grid system css even in tables

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
 <tr>
  <td class="col-md-6">one</td>
  <td class="col-md-4">two</td>
  <td class="col-md-2">three</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="col-md-6">one</td>
  <td class="col-md-4">twoooooooo00</td>
  <td class="col-md-2">three</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
<tr>
 <td class="col-md-6">one</td>
 <td class="col-md-4">two</td>
 <td class="col-md-2">three</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="col-md-6">one</td>
 <td class="col-md-4">two</td>
 <td class="col-md-2">three</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/kk9tvzxw/1/

Caution, it will not save you in all cases such as if you had a single word without space that overflowed the default width.

You may want to go ahead and define the col-sm- and col-lg- on there after viewing it with different sizes but this should get you going.

Comment: I don't think this is responsive -if I use this in a small screen, the columns aren't aligned anymore. is there a way to still use responsive?

Comment: With bootstrap grid system you define how each width should react based on the screen size (noted that in the answer but guess it was unclear)  you stack the classes in the element to tell it exactly how to scale based on the screen size. for example you would do <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-6"> to tell the element how it will scale based upon how the users screen. My example was only showing how to define it for medium size screens, you can add the col-sm-whateverWidth if you want it to react the same for mobile screen and such.

Comment: It seems that if you have a `<thead>` section, you could put the `col-md-whatever` on the `<th>` elements rather than having to put it on each `<td>`. It also seems that you can just manually set the width of the cells rather than using bootstrap's grid.